# Mongoose how to search array in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array with dates. User passes 2 dates: start and stop. I generate array with dates between these dates. Then I have to check in my model if any date from array is in that model. If there's no date (or dates) from array then I want this car, else - i don't want it. How to write whis mongoose query?

I have this model:

```
const CarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    mark:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    model:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,},
    available: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,},
    reserved:{
        type:[Date],

    },
    pic_1:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    pic_2:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },


},
{ collection: 'cars' }
)
```

Lets suppose user passes 2 dates `12-02-2021` and  `16-02-2021`. My method generates array with all dates betweeen `array = [12-02-2012,13-02-2021,14-02-2021 ... 16-02-2021]` in my model i have field `reserved`  - this is array as well. How to take from database only that cars which field `reserved` doesn't contains ANY date from `array`?

`Car.find({??what here??});`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/HpliQ8Q70uM

Use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)  for - doesn't contains ANY date from array

> $nin selects the documents where:
>
> the field value is not in the specified array or the field does not
> exist.

```
db.collection.find({
  reserved: {
    $nin: [
      "12-02-2021",
      "12-04-2021"
    ]
  }
})
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/ewG_6dQ1UaL

Use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) if you want to match values from array

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

```
db.collection.find({
  reserved: {
    $in: [
      "12-02-2021", "12-04-2021"
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: @TheTrainer Glad, i could help :)